# Mysql unable to store emoji in utf8mb4 collation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't store emoji characters in mysql datatbase.

I searched a lot, but again fails. I have followed [this tutorial](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) and changed these variables from **Variables tab** in phpmyadmin.

```
| Variable_name          | Value
----------------------------
character_set_client     | utf8
character_set_connection | utf8mb4
character_set_database   | utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem | binary
character_set_results    | utf8
character_set_server     | utf8mb4
character_set_system     | utf8
collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**NOTE:** set_client and set_result are also `utf8mb4` in Variables tab in phpmyadmin.

I even added these lines in my.ini file:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But again no result!! I just get `????` instead of emoji. Any idea?

**Edit:** `SHOW CREATE TABLE emoji` result

```
 CREATE TABLE `emoji` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `emj_text` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `emj_text` (`emj_text`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Exactly 1 Emoji turned into exactly 4 question marks?  "Again" -- meaning you did a new `INSERT`?

Comment: I expect `????` to occur only when the _column_ is declared `latin1` (other single-byte charset).

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrasing https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 :

Question Marks (regular ones, not black diamonds) (Se?or for Señor):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8mb4. Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.  (That is, check phpmyadmin for `utf8mb4`.

Once `????` is stored, the Emoji is lost.  That is, the `INSERT` side has the problem.  The `SELECT` side *may* also have a problem.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't understand the first two items you mentioned about. The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8mb4 **and** The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8mb4! Would you please explain more that what I'm going to do?

Comment: The Emoji are coming from some source.  Very likely they are encoded in UTF-8; let's assume that is the case.  Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the code that does the connection to the database.  Perhaps it is a phpmyadmin config.

Comment: utf8mb4 (inside mysql) is the same as UTF-8 (outside mysql).

Comment: For `show create table` , please see edit part in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I followed the [tutorial](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) you posted above and altered my Laravel/SQL Configuration as follows:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',              //correct charset for emojis
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',   //proper collation
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

and that worked!

Comment: Thanks Roberto. The issue was related to my mysql version. Cheers.